# Limit points and isolated points

Tags: real-analysis

The following is the definition of a limit point given in my text:

> A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if and only if there exists
>    a convergent sequence $(a_n)$ contained in $A$ where $x = \lim a_n$
>    and $a_n \neq x$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$.

and the following is the definition of an isolated point:

> A point $a \in A \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ is an isolated point of $A$ if
>   it is not a limit point of $A$.

I am trying to negate the definition of the limit point to arrive at an equivalent definition for an isolated point, would the following be correct?

> A point $a \in A$ is an isolated point of $A$ if every convergent sequence
>    $(a_n)$ contained in $A$ that satisfies $a = \lim a_n$ is one such
>    that $a_n = a$ eventually.

But I also thought of the following definition:

> A point $a \in A$ is an isolated point of $A$ if the *only* convergent
>    sequence contained in $A$ that satisfies $a = \lim a_n$ is one such 
>    that $a_n = a$ eventually.

Which one is the correct negation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former. The later options makes no sense because, in general, there is more than one convergent sequence satisfying the conditions that you described.