# Limit point of a sequence with pairwise different elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence in $\emptyset\neq D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, where $D$ is an open set, with $a_i\neq a_j$ for all $i\neq j$ and limit $a\in D$. Can we conclude that $a$ is a limit point of $D$?

My attempt: Taking a limit $j\to\infty$ in $a_i\neq a_j$ for all $i\neq j$ yields $a_i\neq a$ for all $i$. Then $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $D\setminus \{a\}$ with $a_n\to a$ and $a$ is a limit point of $D$.

However, I guess we can not take the limit $j\to\infty$ as the sequence $a_1=0,\,\, a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 2$ satisfies $a_i\neq a_j$ for all $i\neq j$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0 = a_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have found the answer to my question. Let us assume that $a$ is an isolated point of $D$. Then, according to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308001/limit-points-and-isolated-points), we have that $a_n = a$ eventually. Thus, we find $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n = a$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Choosing $n=n_0$ and $n=n_0+1$ yields $a_{n_0} = a = a_{n_0+1}$, a contradiction. But $a$ is an isolated point if and only if it is not a limit point by the post above, so $a$ is indeed a limit point.

Comment: Good :) You should accept this answer to show the question is done.